# Teamcity plugin for Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, teamcity, delphi-ide

Does anybody know if there is any Teamcity plugin for Delphi-IDE like the one for Visualstudio, which enables running personalbuilds directly from the IDE?

thank you

Comment: Why not use finalbuilder, which is actually included in some editions of Delphi XE, and which is particularly good at building Delphi stuff.  Secondly, have you tried using the Tools menu to launch a build? You can add whatever you want there. Including running MSBuild yourself, so I am not sure what TeamCity would be doing other than calling MSBuild for you..

Comment: +1, this is a nice business opportunity for OpenTools experts

Comment: @Warren for personal builds in TeamCity, [the modified files are submitted to the server bypassing the VCS](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/features/supported_platforms.html#Notification_and_Monitoring), which is different from a local build, because the developer workstation will not have the additional load of doing the build and tests

Comment: Sounds like MSBuild on the command line would do that too, since it's using the working copy. Still can't see why TeamCity adds anything to the mix.

Comment: @Warren thank you for the information, this sounds really interesting but we have a project with with C# and Delphi, both use Teamcity which available for VS as a plugin, currently we use VS to run a personal build of Delphi changes which is not really comfortable. Main reason for Teamcity are Personalbuilds, anyway how would MSBuild enable personal builds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your VCS is Git or Mercurial, it is also possble to define a trigger on your feature branches, which will run the personal build automatically:

> ***Remote run on changes in DVCSs branches**: New build trigger added that
>   watches for commits into Git or Mercurial branches and adds personal
>   build to the build queue when commit detected.*

Found on: http://blog.caraulean.com/2011/05/31/quick-tip-configure-teamcity-6-5-to-run-a-personal-build-when-youve-committed-to-a-branch/

Comment: thank you for the answer, we are using this feature allready, it works with SVN too, its really neat one.